# How to call two different API's on same master Page,on which views of two different VC(Test/Packages) added as child view.For swift 3(ios)

Tags: ios, swift3

Kindly go through below mentioned scenario  and tell me required solution,
On master view controller , I have designed two buttons ,below that scrollview, on click of button I am loading view of viewcontroller1 ,on that showing list of tests getting from Api, on 2nd button click scrollview shows view of viewcontroller2 ,on that showing list of packages from api.
Now an  issue is that, when I switch to master view controlle, it dosent shows data on tableview of viewcontroller1, it shows only for viewcontroller2
How can I call these two different api’s ?
kindly go through image ,it shows data on package only, not showing data on test button selection .[image]

Comment: Did you reload table data again ? Otherwise because you are using tabBar so when you click on HomeButton you must reload item at that index

Comment: add some code viewcontroller1 and 2 api call, and adding child view, U have to reload your tableview on main thread in this scenario

Comment: yes on callback delgate method i have been reloaded respective tableview